# Python unittest "FileNotFoundError"

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to implement tests for a class, here is the test code:

```
import unittest

from analyzer.etl import DotaPlayer


class TestDotaPlayer(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.player = DotaPlayer(3)

    def test_check_keywords(self):
        print(self.player)
        response_json = {
            "match_id": 6135452599,
            "player_slot": 2,
            "duration": 1926,
            "game_mode": 22,
            "lobby_type": 7,
            "hero_id": 129,
            "start_time": 1628968743,
            "skill": 2,
            "leaver_status": 4,
            "party_size": 3,
        }
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
            self.player.check_keywords(response_json)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

but when I run the test it raises this error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: builtins.tuple: (<class 'FileNotFoundError'>, FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'), <traceback object at 0x000001FAB6493C80>)
```

The function I want to test is:

```
@staticmethod
    def check_keywords(response_json):
        logger = logger_create()
        keywords = ("kills", "assists", "deaths")
        if all(keys in response_json for keys in keywords):
            msg = dict()
            msg["code"] = 2
            msg["message"] = f"Player misses {keywords} for computing the KPI"
            logger.error(msg)
            sys.exit()
        else:
            return response_json
```

And the script structure is the following:

```
project/
│
├── analyzer/
│   └── __init__.py
|        etl.py
|
|__ helpers/
|    └── __init__.py
|        driver.py
|        utilities.py
|
│
└── tests/
    |
    └──init__.py
       test_player.py
```

With the data from the test the method should raise SystemExit error, which works when I try to test it by calling it, but for some reason it doesn't work here.

P.S
This is logger_create function, which creates logger and adds handler to it:

```
def logger_create():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    if not logger.hasHandlers():
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s : %(asctime)s :: %(message)s")
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(
            filename=os.path.join(
                os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir)),
                "log","logger_new.log"
            )
        )
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

Comment: This is not a complete example. If I had to guess, I'd say `logger_create` is the problem, but `DotaPlayer.__init__` is a suspect as well. Please read [mcve].

Comment: When I comment out logging lines it runs without error, but still can not figure out how to run it smoothly with logging commands

Comment: So what does `logger_create` actually do? I suspect it is trying (and failing) to open a log file for writing.

Comment: It creates a logger and adds handler to it, it only doesn't work with testing, on a run it creates the log file, I will edit the post to include that function.

Comment: The `Logger` instance will create `logger_new.log` if necessary, but I think it requires the directory to already exist. Just constructing the path is not sufficient.

Comment: Done, instead of `logger = logger_create()` I did `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`